# Ternary association VS association class

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I was wondering, are these 2 class diagrams equivalent EXCEPT the fact that in diagram A, a student doesn't have to have a study program?
 The way I see it - for example in diagram B a study program can have many students, and for each one of them, an enrollment is created. Diagram A states that for each pair (Study Program, Enrollment) exists one student, so this could also convey the idea that a Study Program has many students, and for each one exists an enrollment.
The difference between these cases could be that in diagram A, a student may exist on its own, while in diagram B it needs to have at least one study program (and consequently an enrollment as well).
Is my logic correct here?

A)

[image]

B)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

Quotes from the UML 2.5 specification:

> For an Association with N memberEnds, choose any N-1 ends. Let the Property that constitutes the other end be called
>   oep, so that the Classifiers at the chosen N-1 ends are the context for oep. Associate specific instances with
>   the context ends. Then the collection of links of the Association that refer to these specific instances will identify a set
>   of instances at oep. The value represented by oep is a collection calculated from this set as follows: All of the
>   instances in the set occur in the collection, and nothing else does. The cardinality of this collection is its size. The multiplicity of
>   oep constrains this cardinality.

The following quote is especially interesting for your example:

> A lower multiplicity for an end of an n-ary Association of 1 (or more) implies that one link (or more) must exist for every possible combination of values for the other ends.

So, your ternary association defines the following business rules:

- For every combination of Study Program and Student, there is exactly one Enrollment.
- For every combination of Study Program and Enrollment, there is exactly one Student.
- For every combination of Student and Enrollment, there is exactly one Study Program.

All these business rules also apply to diagram B. But diagram B defines an additional rule: Every Student is associated to at least one Study Program (1..*).

Comment: I saw that question, but there seems to be a disagreement between the answerers. For example, the last answer in that post reinforces my statement (I think) by stating that a multiplicity in a ternary association only regards pairs of the other 2 classes, while the first answer has your opinion. Maybe it is just unspecified...

Comment: You are right. I have digged into the UML spec and now I see my answer was completely wrong. I have rewritten it.